# Maximize minimized windows on app switcher by default

Tags: window-manager, multitasking

When selecting an app with the app switcher (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>) it will do nothing if the window happens to be minimized (or the app is active but doesn't have windows open).

In this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/405120/115612) I was informed that you can hold <kbd>OPT</kbd> to maximize it.

Now, I don't really understand the UX. Why is not bringing the windows to the foreground the default? It seems to me pretty natural that if you select an application you want to open it and not a possible "do nothing" event depending on the last state the window was in. Are you supposed to remember the state of all your windows to see if you have to press <kbd>OPT</kbd> or not? Or press always <kbd>OPT</kbd>, which is tedious?

Is there a way to make "simply always show the window" the default?

Comment: Is there a reason you use the rather random cmd/tab structure rather than Spaces? Since that was introduced I don't think I've ever had to minimise a window.

Comment: How do I use spaces to switch quickly from one window to another?

Comment: I use Spaces, but so far haven't figured how to fully control it with the keyboard. All I want is to be able to quickly (and reliably) switch from one window to another, using the keyboard.

Comment: I did a couple of Spaces answers, one here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 & one on superuser… https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 See if they're any help.

Comment: @Tetsujin I read your posts. Quite useful, thanks. A pity that it's not possible to use full screen. Without the menu bar it's almost not necessary but it would still be nicer. Either way I still think that the app switcher's UX is weird/bad.

Comment: Welcome :) tbh, I've always loved Spaces & hated fullscreen. One does [almost] everything I need & the other absolutely ruins that setup. I've steered clear of it since it was first introduced, because they completely forgot to integrate it properly into Spaces. I've never used Cmd/Tab either, because it's so random, too much clicking to make a simple move to an app that wasn't just the 'last used'. Having Spaces hot-keyed means I **always** know where my app is.

Comment: I definitely agree! Hopefully they'll integrate fullscreen properly at some point. It's a bit sad that Apple, known to be so dedicated to UX, has glossed over this. Having to enable manually the shortcuts in the prefs for the added workspaces is also not ideal.